# how to export pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

my code index.blade.php

```
 <div class="content-body">
                <div class="row" id="basic-table">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                        
                                    <div id="hidden-element" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 float-right"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i>Export PDF</div>

                                <h4 class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
                                    REPORT
                                </h4>
                          

                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table mb-0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>NAME</th>
                                                    <th>COMPANY</th>
                                                    <th>LOCATION</th>
                                                    <th>IN</th>
                                                    <th>OUT</th>
                                                    <TH>DESCRIPTION</TH>
                                                    {{-- <th>STATUS</th> --}}
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                              
                                                @foreach ($absen as $data)
                                                    
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>{{ $data->name ?? '' }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $data->alias ?? '' }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $data->location_name ?? '' }}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <span class="badge badge-success">
                                                                {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->in_time)->format('H:i:s') }}
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <span class=" @if ($data->out_time != null) badge badge-info @else  @endif">
                                                                @if ($data->out_time != null)
                                                                    {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->out_time)->format('H:i:s') }}
                                                                @else
                                                                    {{ '-' }}
                                                                @endif
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>{{ $is_late }}</td>
                                                        {{-- <td>{{ $data->note ?? '-' }}</td> --}}
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endforeach

                                             
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

I use new jsPDF but a href button can't be clicked or it doesn't work, is there any other javascript to make export to pdf.

my code export my data pdf with javascript

```
       <script>
           var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
           var specialElementHandlers = {
               '#hidden-element': function (element, renderer) {
                   return true;
               }
           };
           var doc = new jsPDF({
               orientation: 'landscape'
           });
           doc.setFont("courier");
           doc.setFontType("normal");
           doc.setFontSize(24);
           doc.setTextColor(100);
           doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
               'width': 170,
               'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
           });

       </script>
```

i want to export data to pdf using javascript in view laravel, my current way has not worked, is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Where is `elementHTML` defined? You are using it in `doc.fromHTML(...)`

Comment: Where's the code that tries to do something with the created document? All I see is code that creates one, that is then seemingly abandoned.

Comment: that code wouldn't "export" anything - you fell short of actually doing anything with `doc`

Comment: seems all you need is `doc.save()`